# Issues using py2exe, psutil library errors

Tags: python, py2exe, psutil

I'm trying to use py2exe for making a python program exe. 
Until now it was working perfectly, but in the new version of the program I'm using psutil library and it makes some problems to some people. 
In my computer, it works perfectly, I can start the exe file without any issues. 
But on other computers, the exe program makes a problems and it creates a error log, here is it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "guard.pyw", line 10, in <module>
File "psutil\__init__.pyc", line 126, in <module>
File "psutil\_pswindows.pyc", line 16, in <module>
File "psutil\_psutil_windows.pyc", line 12, in <module>
File "psutil\_psutil_windows.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1.
```

I have no idea why it happens, especially when it works fine in my computer. 
Here is the setup.py file of the py2exe program, maybe the problem is there:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup (windows = ['guard.pyw'],
    options = { 'py2exe' : {'packages':['Tkinter'], 'compressed': True}},
    dll_excludes=['msvcr71.dll', "IPHLPAPI.DLL", "NSI.dll",  "WINNSI.DLL", "WTSAPI32.dll"])
```

Does anyone have an idea about how to fix that issue? **Thanks in advance :)**

Comment: 32/64-bit mismatch in a DLL used by `psutil`.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: That I do not know. See that the installed psutil version is appropriate for the Python version that you're using py2exe with.

Comment: You can also try using http://www.pyinstaller.org/ I think its better than py2exe

Comment: My computer is 64 bit, the program works here perfectly. In another computer, which 64 bit too, it doesn't work. ( different windows, my windows is 7 and the another windows is 10 )

Comment: If you compile for 32 bits, it should work on both 64 and 32 bits machines. You can create a VirtualBox of a 32 bits windows, and run your py2exe on it.